# Find highest subscriber count using MAX sql isn't working

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm trying to find the top 3 three highest subscribers using the `MAX` sql query

I've tried (in PHP SQL)- 
`SELECT MAX(subscriber) AS 'subscriber' FROM user;`
and 
`SELECT MAX(subscriber) FROM user;`

In the database, there are 5 users. There are only 4 user with subscribers.

User 1 - 30 subscribers

User 2 - 40 subscribers

User 3 - 50 subscribers

User 4 - 60 subscribers

**So it should be ranked:**

First Place - User 4 - 60 subscribers

Second Place -  User 3 - 50 subscribers

Third Place - User 2 - 40 subscribers

What query do I use to make it echo the top three users with the top three subscribers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need order by number of `subscriber`

```
SELECT user.username. user.subscribers 
FROM user
ORDER BY user.subscribers DESC
Limit 3;
```

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT username, subscribers FROM user ORDER BY subscribe DESC";` AND `SELECT username, subscribers FROM user ORDER BY subscribe DESC LIMIT 3 TOP 3`  I did those and I didn't receive any results

Comment: did you run the sql direct on mysql for testing?

Comment: What is the field name `subscribers` or `subscribe`, should be the same on both

Comment: Nevermind, I did -  `SELECT username, subscribers FROM user ORDER BY subscribers DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1`   and I got what I needed. Thanks :)